# Get authorization code from Keycloak token endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

It is written in the keycloak documentation that the Token Endpoint can be used for  **obtaining a temporary code in the Authorization Code Flow** or for obtaining tokens via the Implicit Flow, Direct Grants, or Client Grants.

But even with response_type=code , I can't get an authorization code: only a token. How can I do that?

My test request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e103dff9-7b25-4f8f-886b-2af73efee561,e8f92a85-1489-4d7f-b89f-76cfe85e9c68' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 94' \
  -d 'grant_type=password&username=login&password=pwd&client_id=my-app&response_type=code'
```

Source : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#keycloak-server-oidc-uri-endpoints

Answer (score 3):

`response_type` can be only used in authorization request to authorization endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth`) and it will be ignored in this case (in token request). Authorization code can be got from authorization endpoint as follows:

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=my-ap&redirect_uri=https://...&response_type=code

See also:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

Comment: But with this endpoint, won't I always get the login page? "grant_type=password" and "prompt=none" seem to be ignored ("prompt" does not exist with OAuth2, but is from OIDC)

Comment: `prompt` can be only used in authentication (authorization) request and it will be ignored. Please refer to: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: it is not possibble at all to send credentials and get an authorization code as a response with a single request?

Comment: Do you wan to get an access token without authentication for end-user, don't you? If so, you can use [Client Credentials Grant](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4).

Comment: No, I need to set up a SSO between a set of sites managed by Keycloak and another one which have it's own Identity Provider.